# c++ can i declare class member and initialized it in the constructor

Tags: c++

```
class Monitor {
public:
    Monitor(string someData);
    Person person_;
}

class Person {
public:
    Person(string personId);
}
```

Person has no default constructor. it has one argument constructor.
I can initialize it only **inside** Monitor constructor.
I come from java where declaration is only pointer , so you don’t need to initialize new instance when you declare.

What is the best practice for class member that doesn’t has default constructor?
Should i add default constructor (disadvantage - no use for it ) or use pointer .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can, and you always *should*, via the *constructor initializer list*:

```
class Monitor
{
    Person p; 
    bool   state;
    const  int n;
    double & d;

    Monitor(std::string const & pname, double & dbl)
    : p(pname)
    , state(false)
    , n(some_other_function(p, state))
    , d(dbl)
    {
         // constructor body should be as short as possible
    }

    // ...

};
```

As you can see, initializing is not just a gimmick; rather, it's a profound necessity of the C++ type system: There are lots of variables which *must* be initialized and cannot be assigned to, such as constants and references, but also user-defined types without default constructor. (And even if there *was* a default constructor, you would need an assignment operator, and it would in any case still be wasteful to construct something you don't want just to overwrite it a moment later.)

Pay attention also to the order in which your class constituents are constructed: When you create a new instance of your class, the member objects are constructed first, in the order in which they are declared in the class definition, but *initialized as specified in the initializer list*. After all the members are constructed, the *body* of the constructor runs.

Actually, there's one other thing that is constructed even before the member objects: base subobjects. Naturally, their initializer too goes in the initializer list:

```
struct Foo { Foo(int, bool);               /* ... */ };
struct Bar { Bar(std::string const &, int) /* ... */ };

class Monitor : public Foo, private Bar
{
    Person p;

    Monitor(std::string const & pname, int a, int b)
    : Foo(a, a == b)
    , Bar(pname, b)
    , p(pname)
    {
        // constructor body
    }

    // ...
};
```

It is highly recommended (though not enforced) that you write the initializers in the constructor initializer list in the same order in which they will be executed!

Comment: I can initialize it only inside the Monitor constructor.

Comment: @user1495181: Make a helper function, like I did for `n`!